# Read data from kafka and print in apache beam

Tags: python, apache-beam

I am like super new to apache beam and i am trying to read data from a kafka topic and then print on screen.. here is what i am trying but i think i am not sure about the print part

```
class LogProcessor(beam.DoFn):
      def process(self, element):
          print(element)


(p
 | 'read' >> ReadFromKafka(cluster='mykafkacluster',topic='funny')
 | 'print' >> beam.ParDo(LogProcessor())
 )
```

Can someone help me with the LogProcessor() part on how exactly that works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `beam.Map` with a function thats logs then returns each element in the `PCollection` :

```
import logging

def log_element(elem):
    logging.info(elem)
    return elem
   

(p
 | 'read' >> ReadFromKafka(cluster='mykafkacluster',topic='funny')
 | 'print' >> beam.Map(log_element)
 )
```

Then you will see the logs in the `Dataflow` UI console or in `Cloud Logging`.

Comment: You can write this even simpler with `beam.Map(logging.info)`. Note that the logging happens on the worker, which may not be local (e.g. it could be in a docker image or on a remote machine).

Comment: Thanks @robertwb, I prefer to use a function that returns the element after logging it, to mark explicitly the intention. A map takes a pure function that returns an element. In Python it’s possible to implement the function as you proposed but in other strongly typed languages it’s not possible. For the log in worker you are right :)

Comment: @Ricko have you solved your issue ?